# Changing Listing and Figure caption system in Platex

Tags: floats, numbering, listings, platex

I'm working with platex (the Japanese latex compiler) and I'm trying to change the caption system for Listings and Figures. For both I would like the numbering to be based on section so if its a figure or Listing in section 2 I want it to be in the style of 2.1

Also I want to change the tag Listing to list.

The doctype I'm using is jarticle because its the only type I found that works with Japanese letters.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

An example of my current code is as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{jarticle}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}
\title{title}
\author{name}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\vfill
\tableofcontents
\end{titlepage}

\section{Basics}
\normalsize
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=200pt]{1.eps}
\caption{some caption}%
\end{figure}

\section{Bar}
\normalsize
\scriptsize
\lstset{numbers=left, stepnumber=5, caption={text}, escapeinside={\%*}{*)}, frame=single, tabsize=2}
\begin{lstlisting}
code here
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Johan please do not change the question to add a solution. The answer is already visible below.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `\@addtoreset{figure}{section}` command in combination with `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}`. See [this](http://www.let.rug.nl/alfa/tex/tetex30/help/faq/uktug-faq/FAQ-addtoreset.html) page.

To say something about changing the listing name it would be helpful to see which package you use to format them. Pleas create a minimal working example (MWE).

Here’s mine which shows everything you’ll need I think…

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{List}% [1]
\makeatletter% [2]
    \@addtoreset{lstlisting}{section}% [3]
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{% [4]
    \renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}}%[5]
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
Content ...

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Test]
Test ...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

**Notes:**
[1] Change the name of listings
[2] Necessary to use command containing `@`
[3] Lets the listing counter be resetted in a new section
[4] Necessary because `\thelstlistings` is undefined before begin document.
[5] Renew number layout.

---

As egreg said thers a second way with the `chngcntr` package, maybe one prefer this way …

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{List}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
Content ...

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Test]
Test ...
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One can simplify by loading **chngcntr** and saying only `\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}` inside `\AtBeginDocument` (no `\@addtoreset` is needed, and `\counterwithin` automatically redefines `\the...`)

Comment: @egreg: Thank. I read it on the linked page in my solution after posting. I like the ways with no extra packages. I added an extra example.

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? :) It's unfortunate that the LaTeX kernel doesn't provide a user interface for linking counters; **chngcntr** is powerful and unobtrusive.

Comment: @egreg: I see, maybe I can remember the package in future … :-)